# Show URL error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm parsing the URL in Rails controller using `URI.parse`, i.e.

```
URI.parse(user_URL)
```

When the user inputs something such as `%`, the webpage raises the error

```
bad URI(is not URI?): %
```

and shows error page.

Rather, I'd like it to go to my page which says "Your URL % is not valid". Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the `parse` call in a `begin`/`end` block with a `rescue` for the case where the URL is invalid:

```
begin
  URI.parse(user_URL)
  ... do some stuff ...
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  redirect_to :invalid_url_page, :url => user_URL
end
```

Then in your `invalid_url_page` controller action (or whatever you call that action), you can access the invalid url with `params[:url]`. In the view associated with that action, you can display the message "Your URL % is not valid" with:

```
Your URL <%= params[:url] %> is not valid.
```